# Performant replacement for IPython !shell-command magic

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

On Google Colab, using:

```
! shell-command
```

is extremely slooooooooooooooooooooow.

Here's a test:

```
import os
%timeit os.system('date > /dev/null')
%timeit ! date > /dev/null
```

Gives output:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 8.58 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop
```

This makes using `! command` 180 times slower than using `system()` for a simple command.

How can I avoid using `! command` while still getting the stdout / stderr  written to the output cell in real time?

In particular, I would like to be able to display things like `wget`'s dynamic progress bar on a single screen line, but I would settle for a solution which would write out a new line for each progress bar update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `subprocess.check_output`. It works similar to `!`, but you need to split the command into array first.

Comment: With a loop that causes one CPU to go to 100%? How to distinguish between no data available and end of process?

Answer (score 0):

[Python Run External Command And Get Output On Screen or In Variable](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/) gives:

```
import subprocess, sys

## command to run - tcp only ##
cmd = "/usr/sbin/netstat -p tcp -f inet"

## run it ##
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

## But do not wait till netstat finish, start displaying output immediately ##
while True:
    out = p.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note that this doesn't capture or print STDERR. Edits welcome.